# Auto-Archive Published Articles using Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, knowledge, action, archive

**TLDR - *What Knowledge **object** and **Id field** should I be using for the Knowledge Article Action: Archive online knowledge articles?***

Posted on Trailhead [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007F5cz5SAB), but wasn't able to get my flow working.

I've been playing around with the Action: **Archive online knowledge articles**, but I am having no luck getting my flow to work.

When debugging, an error is returned but there is no error message being returned.

**What I'm attempting to do?**

- Create a scheduled flow (run daily) to auto-archive knowledge articles if a formula field is true.

**Steps to make this happen?**

1. Create a Scheduled Flow with a daily frequency on the Knowledge (Knowledge_kav) object with entry criteria to check if formula = true

- Object: Knowledge_kav (Concrete)

2. Get Records element to use the (Abstract) object: "Knowledge Article Version"

- IsLatestVersion = True
- Knowledge Article Version.Id = $Record.Id (Global Record Variable)

3. Create a Text Collection Variable (String) to store the KnowledgeArticleVersion.Id (I also tried Knowledge_kav.Id without any success)
4. Create a Assignment element to add the KnowledgeArticleVersion.Id from the Get Records element and store in the Text Collection variable (step 3)
5. Create a Action: Archive online knowledge articles and assigned the Text Collection variable for the list of Ids to be archived

- Debug fails at the very last action, when it attempts to use the Archive online knowledge article action for the list of Ids
  Any pointers with where I am going wrong? #Flow #Knowledge Article

**Flow & Entry Criteria**
[[image]

**Get Records**
[image]

**Assignment**
[image]

**Knowledge Article Action**
[image]

**Debug Log**
[image]